# Proving (or disproving) the existence of multiple (or unique) natural numbers of given form.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

> Prove (or disprove) that there are infinitely many natural numbers of the form: $$n=\dfrac{25p^2-124q^2}{100q^2}$$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers with $q\neq 0$.

Now a more general question can be proving (or disproving) the existence of infinitely many natural numbers of the form $n=\dfrac{ap^2-bq^2}{cq^2}$, but I don't have any idea how to prove it, or start.

Can anybody please help?

***THANKS***

Comment: @user2661923 Please consider not dropping too many questions at a time, as it may be perceived as some kind of "interrogation" (at least it strikes as a tad unfriendly). Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

With $q^2(100n + 124) = 25p^2$, let $r = (q/5)$.

Then $q^2[100(n+1) + 24] = 25p^2 \implies r^2[100(n+1) + 24] = p^2.$

Therefore, I would explore $100(n+1) + 24$ being a perfect square.

If $(10a + s)^2 \equiv 24 \pmod{100}$, then so is
$[100(b) + 10(a) + s]^2 ~:~ a,s \leq 9.$

What values for $a,s$ will result in
$(10a + s)^2 \equiv 24 \pmod{100}$?

Consider $r^2 \times (100b + 10a + s)^2 = p^2.$

Comment: I think it would suffice to prove that at least one $a,s$ exist satisfying these conditions, which we can easily find (say $a=1$ and $s=8$), because we have the freedom to choose $b$, hence giving infinite values of $n$, with $q$ adjusting according to those values of $n$, hence completing the solution, right?

Comment: @DevanshKamra For the first problem that you posed, absolutely.  However, if it were me, I would try for a more complete solution to the first problem, only as a means of *practicing*, to develop/stretch my intuition, before attacking the second problem.

Comment: Actually proving the first problem was a required step in my solution for some other problem, and the second problem (the generalization) just popped into my mind while writing this question down, with no connection to the problem I was solving before. Although looking at it, the second problem feels like a good independent problem to tackle with, which I'll be trying by myself. Thanks a lot for help, I appreciate it (+1)